# sshfs mount directory disappears in Finder

Tags: macos

OSX High Sierra, `sshfs` setup:

```
sshfs username@hostname:/tmp/mnt/cruzer64 /Users/user/mount
```

Listing the contents from the command line performs as expected:

```
ls /Users/user/mount
```

The target directory is returned in BASH:

```
la -l /Users/user | grep mount
```

The folder ~/mount disappears from Finder after the sshfs server is mounted.

- Why does the sshfs folder disappear in Finder  and
- What can be done to restore visibility in finder?

The problem / issue is confined to the Finder application

Comment: Does it only disappear from Finder or has the remote filesystem unmounted as well?

Comment: The problem, unexpected disappearance of ~/mount,  is confined to Finder.  BASH works as expected.   Network access to files through sshfs works as expected from command line.

Comment: Have you tried 'SetFile -a v <folder>' to reveal it?

Answer (score 1):

I am using sshfs with macFUSE, both from https://osxfuse.github.io with Monterey (12.0.1).

My mount point shows no change in Terminal, but in Finder, it's name changes to “macFUSE volume 0 (sshfs)” but that is harmless, and it changes back when dismounted.

For a little more about my setup, see https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/2491

If you want something a lot fancier (but not free), see https://mountainduck.io

Comment: Also, if I "open (mount point)" in Terminal, Finder does show the correct things.